# How could I make the border lines so the whole text is in one box? (not 4 boxes)

Tags: border

I want to put my text into a box and then make some transparent white background to it. But first I would like to have it in a box. Now it's in 4 boxes. How could I do that?

```
p {
font-family: Kartika;
width: 450px;
height: 75px;
position: relative;
top: 250px;
left: 400px;
margin: 1px;
padding: 15px;
color: white;
border: 1px solid white;
```

}

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. Please include the code necessary to reproduce your problem.

Comment: why can't I just make a border in css like #div_id { border: 1px white; } ?

Comment: one second, I add more info

Comment: <div class="index_t">
<p>test</p>
<p>test</p>
<p>test</p>
<p>test</p>
</div> 

if I write 

#index_t {
font-family: Kartika;
width: 450px;
height: 75px;
position: relative;
top: 250px;
left: 400px;
margin: 1px;
padding: 15px;
color: white;
border: 1px solid white;
}

in CSS, then why don't I see a border around the paragraphs?

Comment: If you just want to add a border to your `p` tags, then you can set a border with `border: 1px white solid`. Paragraphs don't have a border by default, so you need to specify solid to override that.

Comment: Yes, but I wanted to have a border around the whole div. So all paragraphs have one. Even if I add "solid", it draws a border around every paragraphy, not the div how I wanted to.
Is it understandable? If not let me know

Comment: In that case, you need to apply the style to the div, `div#index_t`, instead of the paragraph.

Answer (score 0):

First set an id

Here is my new code:

```
  <div id="border">
<p>lorem ipsidsodf</p>
<p>shdiohdshd</p>
<p>lshdohgsd</p>
</p>kgdawkad</p>
</div>

p {

width: 450px;
height: 75px;
position: relative;
top: 250px;
left: 400px;
margin: 1px;
padding: 15px;
display:block;
border: 1px solid white;
}
#border{
border:1px solid blue;}
```

jsfiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/e3na9291/

Comment: this works perfectly, but I have 4 p tags, and this would put them separately. I'd like to have all 4 p tags in the same box

Comment: then out them all inside a div with id bor and you will have the desired result

Comment: that's the problem. when I apply the code you put in above to the div it applies for the 4 different paragraphs individually. first thing i tried... should be all of them